# filtro con checkboxs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguente filto con checkboxs, la idea es que el usuario seleccione los checkboxs entre 4 categorias y realize un filtro de los elementos
cada elemento posee 4 datas: (data-plato , data-coc , data-ingre , data-otro ) con valores numericos

**Javascript**

```
$('#prueba').click(function(){
         event.preventDefault();
         query = new Array(new Array(),new Array(),new Array(),new Array());
                    $('.platoid:checked').each(
                        function() {
                            query[0].push($(this).val());
                        }
                    );
                    $('.coccionid:checked').each(
                        function() {
                            query[1].push($(this).val());
                        }
                    );
                    $('.ingredienteid:checked').each(
                        function() {
                            query[2].push($(this).val());
                        }
                    );
                    $('.otroid:checked').each(
                        function() {
                            query[3].push($(this).val());
                        }
                    );


                    $('.bookitem').not(`[data-plato ~= ${query[0]}]`).hide();
                    $('.bookitem').not(`[data-coc ~= ${query[1]}]`).hide();
                    $('.bookitem').not(`[data-ingre ~= ${query[2]}]`).hide();
                    $('.bookitem').not(`[data-otro ~= ${query[3]}]`).hide();
                })
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 bookitem pb-5 text-center" 
data-coc="1 2 " data-plato="20 2 10 " data-ingre="5 8 " data-otro=" " id="1">
    <img src="img/receta.jpg" class="pb-2" alt="test">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/crops/time_small.png" alt="">
    <p class="d-inline">10 minutos</p>
    <img src="img/crops/cook.png" alt="">
    <p class="d-inline">test</p>
    <div class="pt-4">
    <a href="" class="px-3 py-2 addtocart">Agregar a mi libro</a>
</div>
```

mi problema es que si el usuario no marca ningun item en alguna de las categorias tira un error de unrecognized expression y si selecciona mas de uno estaria llegando 0,1 por ejemplo

quizas exista tambien una forma mas sensilla de encarar el problema

Comment: Puedes agregar el HTML para poder ejemplificar el ejercicio, gracias.

Comment: ejemplo de un item
`<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 bookitem pb-5 text-center" 
    data-coc="1 2 " 
    data-plato="20 2 10 " 
    data-ingre="5 8 " 
    data-otro=" " id="1">

    <img src="img/receta.jpg" class="pb-2" alt="test">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/crops/time_small.png" alt="">
    <p class="d-inline">10 minutos</p>
    <img src="img/crops/cook.png" alt="">
    <p class="d-inline">test</p>
    <div class="pt-4">
        <a href="" class="px-3 py-2 addtocart">Agregar a mi libro</a>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: ejemplo de un filtro
`
<h2>Tipo de coccion</h2>
<div class="form-check">                    
    <input class="form-check-input coccionid" type="checkbox" value="1" id="olla">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="olla">
    olla
    </label>
</div>
`

Comment: Da click en editar y agrega ese HTML en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Planteamiento**
Por lo que puedo comprobar has hecho que cada elemento tenga un atributo tipo `data-plato`, `data-coc`, `data-ingre` y `data-otro`. Y que ese elemento sea *multivaluado*

Y luego recorres los elementos de cada tipo para poder añadir las opciones que tiene cada uno.

**Tu problema**
No se muestran correctamente ya que no ejecutas correctamente el filtro. La forma más fácil de ejecutarlo es haciendo una función y sacando el array `query` fuera del evento `click` (para que se pueda llamar dentro de dicha función) o podrías pasarle el array a la función que también es una posibilidad

**Función:**
Así es como lo haría yo:

```
function filtrado(){
    var platos=query[0];
    var coccion=query[1];
    var ingredientes=query[2];
    var otro=query[3];
    $(".bookitem").each(function(){
        //ignoreCase es como bien dice para ignorar las mayusculas
        var pl=$(this).attr("data-plato").ignoreCase;
        var cc=$(this).attr("data-coc").ignoreCase;
        var ingr=$(this).attr("data-ingre").ignoreCase;
        var otr=$(this).attr("data-otro").ignoreCase;
        //Esté if comprueba si cumple todos los requisitos puestos
        if(checkinarray(pl,platos)
            &&checkinarray(cc,coccion)
            &&checkinarray(ingr,ingredientes)
            &&checkinarray(otr,otro)
        ){
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
function checkinarray(str,ar){
    //Comprobamos si el array está vacio
    if(ar.length>0){
        //Separamos los posibles elementos (si hay más de 1)
        //El trim() sirve para eliminar los espacios sobrantes
        var component=str.trim().split(" ");
        var existe=false;
        for(i=0;i<component.length;i++){
            //El includes detecta si existe en un array un elemento string
            if(ar.includes(component[i])){
                exite=true;
                //El return es para salir del bucle una vez encuentre alguna coincidencia
                return;
            }
        }
        return exite;
    }else{
        //Retornamos true ya que el array está vacio y de está forma admitirá valores
        //vacios
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Tu antiguo código**

```
$('#prueba').click(function(){
         event.preventDefault();

$('#prueba').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //Creación del array
    query = new Array(new Array(),new Array(),new Array(),new Array());
    $('.platoid:checked').each(
        function() {
            query[0].push($(this).val());
        }
    );
    $('.coccionid:checked').each(
        function() {
            query[1].push($(this).val());
        }
    );
    $('.ingredienteid:checked').each(
        function() {
            query[2].push($(this).val());
        }
    );
    $('.otroid:checked').each(
        function() {
            query[3].push($(this).val());
        }
    );
    //Eliminamos los $('x').not(`[data-x ~= ${query[x]}]`).hide(); y
    //insertamos
    filtrado();
});
```

**Algunas referencias:**
[include() (W3School)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)
[ignoreCase (W3School)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_ignorecase.asp)
[trim() (W3School)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)
[split() (W3School)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: dentro de mi codigo al hacer .click deberia seguir armando el array? con los :checked ?

Comment: Si, solo cambias los `$('......').not(`.`).hide();` por `filtrado();` abajo del todo del código lo pone. Aunque lo voy ha separar para que se vea a primera vista

Comment: me dice que TypeError: str is undefined , haciendo un console.log(str) dentro de la funcion checkinarray estoy recibiendo undefined

Comment: lo solucione modificando `var pl=$(this).attr("data-plato").ignoreCase;` a: `var pl=$(this).data("plato");` para todos los casos